# calling awk from python

Tags: python, awk, subprocess

i wanted to call an awk commandline script from python:

```
os.system('''awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\n"} {a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2 FS $3 FS $4} END{for (i in a) {print i a[i]}}' 2_lcsorted.txt > 2_locus_2.txt''')
```

it gives the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{FS="    ";OFS="
awk: cmd. line:1:                     ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{FS="    ";OFS="
awk: cmd. line:1:                     ^ syntax error
256
```

when I use subprocess using subprocess.call, another kind of error pops:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

it runs fine in the shell and all i want to do is to combine all steps in a single python script and for some obvious reasons awk is better for certain processing steps. Can someone please explain me the cause of these errors ?

Comment: What does it do with an `r` before the ''' ?  (ie, `r'''awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\n"} {...`  (The `\n` is being interpreted a step too early)

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? I can see shelling out to `awk` to run a pre-written `awk` script, but why call awk with a hard-coded script when you can just do the same thing in Python?

Comment: @chepner.. i preferred awk because i dont know if python can work on a stream input.. its just that i believe that parsing is faster in awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add, you might be better off using PyAwk: pyawk.sourceforge.net
Also, if you're using subprocess, the problem is that your command should be split. See, subprocess works a bit differently than os.system. subprocces requires that the cmd is a string, not a list. For example,

```
`os.system('''awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS="\n"} {a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2 FS $3 FS $4} 
END {for (i in a) {print i a[i]}}' 2_lcsorted.txt > 2_locus_2.txt''')`
```

Shoudn't be

```
`subprocess.call('''awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS="\n"} {a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2 FS $3 FS $4} 
END {for (i in a) {print i a[i]}}' 2_lcsorted.txt > 2_locus_2.txt''')`
```

That won't work. If you feed subprocess a string, it assumes that that is the path to the command you want to execute. The command needs to be a list. Check out www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/724330. Also, because you're using file redirection, you should use

```
`subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)`
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not want Python to convert `\n` to a newline character (or `\t` to a tab) before feeding the string to `system`. Use `r"""...."""` as jwpat7 suggested. Another possibility is to write something like `... OFS="\\n" ...` in the string.